# Regular expression in sed to replace C++ includes

Tags: c++, include, sed

I'm trying to play with sed, to change all;

```
#include "X"
```

to:

```
#include <X>
```

However I can't seem to find a way to do this! - This is what I've done so far:

```
sed -i 's/#include ".*"/#include <.*>/g' filename
```

I think I'm in need of a variable to save the contains of ".*", i'm just unaware of how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do. Regexps use () to save the contents of a match and a \1 to retrieve it. If you use more than one set of (), then the 2nd match is in \2 , and so on.

```
sed -e 's/#include "\(.*\)"/#include <\1>/g' < filename
```

will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed 's/#include "\(.*\)"/#include <\1>/' x.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`sed -i 's/#include "\(.*\)"/#include <\1>/g' filename`